# How can I display a form on a secondary monitor?

Tags: delphi, screensaver, multiple-monitors

I am writing a screensaver in Delphi. I want is to display a TpresentationFrm on each monitor, fullscreen. To this end, I have written the following (incomplete) program:

```
program ScrTemplate;

uses
  ...

{$R *.res}

type
  TScreenSaverMode = (ssmConfig, ssmDisplay, ssmPreview, ssmPassword);

function GetScreenSaverMode: TScreenSaverMode;
begin
  // Some non-interesting code
end;

var
  i: integer;
  presentationForms: array of TpresentationFrm;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;

  case GetScreenSaverMode of
    ssmConfig:
      Application.CreateForm(TconfigFrm, configFrm);
    ssmDisplay:
      begin
        SetLength(presentationForms, Screen.MonitorCount);
        for i := 0 to high(presentationForms) do
        begin
          Application.CreateForm(TpresentationFrm, presentationForms[i]);
          presentationForms[i].BoundsRect := Screen.Monitors[i].BoundsRect;
          presentationForms[i].Visible := true;
        end;
      end
  else
    ShowMessage(GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TScreenSaverMode), integer(GetScreenSaverMode)));
  end;

  Application.Run;
end.
```

When the `ssmDisplay` code is executed, two forms are indeed created (yes, I have exactly two monitors). But they both appear on the first monitor (index 0, but not the primary one).

When stepping through the code, I see that the `Screen.Monitors[i].BoundsRect` are correct, but for some reason the forms obtain incorrect bounds:

```
Watch Name                          Value (TRect: Left, Top, Right, Bottom, ...)
Screen.Monitors[0].BoundsRect   (-1680, 0, 0, 1050, (-1680, 0), (0, 1050))
Screen.Monitors[1].BoundsRect   (0, 0, 1920, 1080, (0, 0), (1920, 1080))

presentationForms[0].BoundsRect (-1680, 0, 0, 1050, (-1680, 0), (0, 1050))
presentationForms[1].BoundsRect (-1920, -30, 0, 1050, (-1920, -30), (0, 1050))
```

The first form get the desired position, but the second does not. Instead of going from x=0 to 1920, it occupies x=-1920 to 0, i.e. it appears on the first monitor, above the first form. What is wrong? What is the proper procedure to accomplish what I want?

Comment: You will have problems on high DPI monitors IF your application does not include the highdpi aware flag in its manifest. In this case, Windows will report a wrong (virtualised) bound rectangle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The form has to be visible in order to set the bounds using BoundRect.

Reverse the lines like this:

```
presentationForms[i].Visible := true;
presentationForms[i].BoundsRect := Screen.Monitors[i].BoundsRect;
```

Comment: Yes, I just have to swap the two lines in the `for` loop: set the visibility first, and then change the bounds!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I try to set the position prematurely.

Replace the `for` loop block with

```
Application.CreateForm(TpresentationFrm, presentationForms[i]);
presentationForms[i].Tag := i;
presentationForms[i].Visible := true;
```

and then write

```
procedure TpresentationFrm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BoundsRect := Screen.Monitors[Tag].BoundsRect;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: You will have problems on high DPI monitors IF your application does not include the highdpi aware flag in its manifest. In this case, Windows will report a wrong (virtualised) bound rectangle.

One solution would be to manually move the form to the screen you, want like this:

```
procedure MoveFormToScreen(Form: TForm; ScreenNo: Integer);
begin
 Assert(Form.Position= poDesigned);
 Assert(Form.Visible= TRUE);

 Form.WindowState:= wsNormal;
 Form.Top := Screen.Monitors[ScreenNo].Top;
 Form.Left:= Screen.Monitors[ScreenNo].Left;
 Form.WindowState:= wsMaximized;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This step I succeeded
For example, we want to display the form on the second monitor, its index is 1

```
program ARPMandiri;
```

uses
 Vcl.Forms,
 SysUtils,
 UMain in 'UMain.pas' {frmMain},
 ........
 ..............................;

{$R *.res}

begin
 Application.Initialize;
 Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
 .............
 Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
 frmMain.Visible := true;
 frmMain.BoundsRect := Screen.Monitors[1].BoundsRect;
 ApplyThemes(frmMain);
 Application.Run;
end.

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
 iTm: Integer;
begin
 Self.Left:= Screen.Monitors[1].Left;
 Self.Top:= Screen.Monitors[1].Top;
 Self.Width:= Screen.Monitors[1].Width;
 Self.Height:= Screen.Monitors[1].Height;
 ...............
 
end;